# Edit control doesn't create property in WiX

Tags: c#, wix

I have a dialog with an Edit control and a Property set to it. When I advance to the next dialog and it calls my custom action (from PushButton Publish), I can't access the Property that should have been created before.

I don't create/declare the property before (using `<Property>`, because I want the Edit control to have the text empty and if I declare the property, then I must assign something to `Value` which causes the text to be filled with it. If I declare, the the CA finds the property.

How can I create the property without a value in the Edit control and be able to access it from CA?

Here is the code:

```xml
<Control Id="EditHost"
         Type="Edit"
         X="150" Y="95"
         Height="17" Width="350"
         Property="SERVER_HOST" />
```

```cs
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult MyCustomAction(Session session)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(session["SERVER_HOST"])
    {
        session.Log("Error!");
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare property with Secure instead of values. This attribute is used to pass the values from Client side to Server side.

```
<Property Id="SERVER_HOST" Secure="yes"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, @Vinoth. I was thinking about not declaring the Property before the actual Edit declaration (to avoid duplicate references, but it is ok). Thanks!